# When is $f^{-1}=1/f\,$?

Tags: reference-request, functions, functional-equations

I seem to remember a nice article that I read many years ago (perhaps in the [American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.maa.org/pubs/monthly.html)) which investigated the question, "Under what conditions on $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is $f^{-1}=1/f\,$?"

Despite my online searches, I cannot locate it. Does anyone have a reference? Or answer to the question---which to the best of my memory was nontrivial (and took a complex variables approach)?

**Edit:** Just to set the record straight, the assumption the authors used in the article was actually this:

*ASSUMPTION. The function $f$ is one-to-one from the positive half-line $(0, \infty)$ onto itself and satisfies $f^{-1}(x)= 1/f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(0,\infty)$.*

Comment: What is $f$, exactly? $f^{-1}=1/f$ when $f\circ f=1/x$, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry, but if I recall correctly, in that article they simply took $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. I will edit the question. Also, they were looking for the most general conditions on $f$ under which the result held, not just particular examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for?

> Russell Euler and James Foran. "On Functions Whose Inverse Is Their Reciprocal." 
>    *Mathematics Magazine*
>   Vol. 54, No. 4 (Sep., 1981), pp. 185-189.  [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2689629?uid=3739664&uid=2134&uid=374815983&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=374815973&uid=3739256&uid=60&sid=21101500325261)

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Comment: I edited to put in the full citation, not just the link.

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in complex solutions, the function $f(z) = z^i$ (using the principal branch) satisfies $f(f(z)) = 1/z$ for $e^{-\pi} < |z| < e^{\pi}$.